# Change label in custom button

Tags: android, android-widget

I need to extends Button vidget there can be overrided label text. For ex:

```
button.seText("bla bla bla bla");
```

and get in view label "bla...bla". It's such as standart `singleLine="true"`, but result like bla bla... is not good for me. 
I created class CustomButton extends Button and now what method I need to override for my result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `lines` attribute of your button `1` and `ellipsize` `middle`.

`SignleLine` is deprecated now.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt that. But can I set max letters count?

Comment: Maxlenght cut the string and not put "...". Ex: I have "Libra" but not "Lib..ry"

Comment: Yes, maxlength cut the string. To achieve what you want you have to write you own button class and set not "Library" text but programatically cut it to "Lib..ry" and then set "Lib..ry" text. (or you can cut this text programatically before settext and not write you own button)

Answer (score 0):

in you layout XML

```
<button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="middle"
   />
```